# How do I retrieve image from ImageRegion in Piranha CMS

Tags: piranha-cms

I'm making a start page and want to let the user change the image for the carousel. The only way I see now to retrieve the image is by its GUID like this:

Index.cshtml

```
@UI.Content("1d2b6621-b7f4-4857-b131-0adcdceb4a57")
```

How would I get it by property name? Something like:

```
@UI.Content("Model.Regions.CarouselImage1.Url")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you region "CarouselImage1" is an ImageRegion you can retrieve the image url with the following:

```
@UI.Content(Model.Regions.CarouselImage1.Id)
```

Comment: Nice! <img src="@UI.Content(Model.Regions.CarouselImage1.Id)" alt="@Model.Regions.CarouselImage1.Name" /> Did the trick but initiated another question.. Saving the image turned it from 1550x500 to 940x345px. Why is that? Even uploading it directly under "Images & Documents" makes it smaller.

Comment: To optimize images for your current application there's a parameter called IMAGE_MAX_WIDTH. This is set to 940 by default but can set to any number. If you allow large images you can still downsize them when using them in your carousel with @UI.Content(id, width).